# The expression $(x+a)(x+1991) +1$ can be factored as a product $(x+b)(x+c)$ where $b,c$ are integers

Tags: algebra-precalculus, quadratics

I need to solve following problem, but don't know to start with, please provide hints and solutions.

Find all integer values of $a$ such that the quadratic expression $(x+a)(x+1991) +1$ can be factored as a product $(x+b)(x+c)$ where $b,c$ are integers .

Comment: Expand both expressions and then equate coefficients.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is equivalent to find $a\in\Bbb{Z}$ such that the equation $L$:
$$(x+a)(x+1991)+1=0$$
has $2$ integer roots.

Notice integer roots exist if the discriminant of $L$ is a perfect square(*), that is ($T$),
$$(1991+a)^2-4(1)(1991a+1)=t^2$$
for some $t\in\Bbb{N^0}$.

Rearrange ($T$) and we get
$$(1991-a)^2-t^2=4$$
$$(1991-a-t)(1991-a+t)=4$$

Since both $1991-a-t$ and $1991-a+t$ are integers, by the pairs
$$(1991-a-t,1991-a+t)=(1,4)/(-1,-4)/(2,2)/(-2,-2)$$

among which the only possible result is $t=0$.

Therefore $a=1989$ or $1993$

---

(*) Quoted from [Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Discriminant): "For a quadratic polynomial with rational coefficients, it factors over the rationals if and only if the discriminant is a square."

(**)It is also obvious that if the discriminant is not a square, the roots will be irrational.