# Find values of $a$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, roots, quadratics, factoring

How do I find an integer $a$ such that that :

$$ (x-a)(x-12)+2$$

can be factorized as $(x+b)(x+c)$ where $b$ and $c$ are integers too.

I have tried expanding the equation and taking the determinant as $k^2$ . But I can't proceed any further from that

Comment: What did you try? Did you multiply out both terms? Did you search before posting? I found [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1870326/the-expression-xax1991-1-can-be-factored-as-a-product-xbxc-wher?rq=1).

Comment: Yes. the x^2 factor cancels out but we get a 3 variable equation

Comment: I have tried expanding the equation and taking the determinant as k^2 . But I can't proceed any further from that

Comment: Perhaps you can include your own workings (using MathJax) in the question. This may help us see what you're missing.

Comment: This question is not duplicate of course.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The equation $$x^2-(a+12)x+12a+2=0$$ has integer roots.

For which we need that there is natural $k$ for which
$$(a+12)^2-48a-8=k^2$$ or
$$(a-12)^2-8=k^2$$ or
$$(a-12-k)(a-12+k)=8$$ and solve a number of systems.

I got $a=9$ or $a=15$.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, equate them:
$$(x-a)(x-12)+2=(x+b)(x+c) \Rightarrow \\
x^2-(a+12)x+12a+2=x^2+(b+c)x+bc \Rightarrow \\
\begin{cases}-a-12=b+c\\ 12a+2=bc\end{cases} \stackrel{12R_1+R_2}{\Rightarrow} \\
-142=12b+12c+bc \Rightarrow \\
(b+12)(c+12)=2 \Rightarrow (b,c)=(-10,-11);(-11,-10);(-13;-14);(-14;-13) \Rightarrow \\
a=-b-c-12=9;15.$$